# Java tells me the charAt method is a variable?

Tags: java, for-loop

Java keeps giving me a compiler error, telling me the charAt method should be a variable and I can't figure out why?
Here's my code:

```
    String s = "12345";

    for (int i=0;i<s.length(); i++){
     s.charAt(i)= s.charAt((i+1)%s.length());

       System.out.println(s);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by using `s.charAt(i)=...`? You can only use variables in the left side of an assignment.

Comment: I'm trying to reprint a new string where the character at i will be the output of the equation on the right

Comment: String is immutable. I suggest you copy the chars you want to a StringBuilder. Note: the character `'1'` is not the same as number `1` it is the ASCII code for 1 i.e. 49.

Answer (score 3):

```
s.charAt(i)= s.charAt((i+1)%s.length());
```

You can't do this in Java. Strings are immutable, and s.charAt(i) evaluates to value, not a variable. This is why it's telling you it should be a variable

Answer (score 1):

A Java `String` is immutable, but there is [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (which is *a mutable sequence of characters*). You could do something like,

```
String str = "12345";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(str);
for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    sb.setCharAt(i, str.charAt((i + 1) % sb.length()));
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

I get

```
23451
```

Comment: @PeterLawrey Edited again, I will just point out that was from the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you are doing a rotation cipher.

```
String s = "12345";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char ch = s.charAt(i+1);
    ch += 1;
    if (ch > '5')
        ch -= 5;
    sb.append(ch);
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

`String` is immutable but `StringBuilder` is mutable and you can use it to create a new String.  Note: the character `1` is the ASCII value of that character or 49. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII so your maths has to take this into account.

If you just want to rotate the characters, you can do

```
String s2 = s.substring(1) + s.charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

`s.charAt(i)= s.charAt((i+1)%s.length());`, you `charAt()` returns a character at a particular index , you can't assign to it.

Answer (score 0):

The result of `charAt()` is a `char` that cannot be assigned. Moreover, `String`s in Java are *immutable*, meaning that there is no mechanism for changing a string after it has been constructed.

Use [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to make a new string from the old one character-by-character:

```
String s = "12345";
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder("12345");
for (int i=0 ; i<s.length() ; i++) {
     res.setCharAt(i, s.charAt((i+1)%s.length()));
}
System.out.println(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or probably you could use an array of char.

```
    char[] s = "12345".toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        s[i] = s[(i + 1) % s.length];
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: You can't print a `char[]` this way. Perhaps you meant to `System.out.println(new String(s))` after the loop.